# What does having multiple width constraints on a single UIButton mean?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

For brevity, I commented creating the left constraint, and am only showing code for creating the width constraint.

As coded, every button in `rowView` is expanded equally. When I remove creating the `widthConstraint`, all the buttons squish down to their intrinsic size (except for the first button in the `rowView`). The first button in the row expands to fill.

```
for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
    if index == 0 {
        // Leftmost button's left edge 
        // constrained to the left edge 
        // of the rowView
    } else {
        // Else constrain button's left edge to 
        // the right edge of the button to the left

        // But what does the below width constraint
        // accomplish?
        let firstButton = buttons[0]
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 800.0)
        rowView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
    }
}
```

So, for each `button` in the button array, create a width constraint on `firstButton` that is equal to the width of `button`, and add that constraint to the `rowView`.

Doesn't this mean I have multiple width constraints on `firstButton`? Or do subsequent width constraints replace previous ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints don't work like regular assignment in programming languages. So assigning one attribute of one item doesn't mean to override it every time. Think about constraints as about equation system because in fact they are equation system. When Autolayout tries to calculate views' sizes it simply solves this equation system based on your constraints. That's why sometimes you see constraints ambiguity warnings inside Storyboards because there is not enough information in your constraints to successfully solve the system and find values for all the variables.

So in your case the system will be like this

```
a = b
a = c
a + b + c = 300
```

You can easily calculate that `a`, `b` and `c` all have value of `100`. All of them are `width` of buttons in your case. And you see that you assign `a` twice but there is not an assignment like in programming languages, but an equal sign like in algebra. So, that's why it is OK to have multiple constraints for one parameter of view but they must be solvable.

If you have constraints one of which tells that width must be `100pt` and another — that `>200pt` there is conflict. And you need to solve it by yourself.

You can read more [here in Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1).

Comment: "..not an assignment like in programming languages, but an equal sign like in algebra.." This is when it clicked for me! Equality, not assignment.